# Maven how to include only selected folders while copying resources

Tags: java, maven, devops, build-tools

Is there any way I can copy only selected folders of resource to new folder in maven.

```
<configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/src/main/targt</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>/src/main/resources/test</directory>
                  <include>folder1</include>

                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>
```

Comment: Share some code with us showing what you have attempted so far...

Comment: "directory" stands for the folder you want to copy and "include" stands for files you want to copy

Comment: I have tried above code, but its not including the directory folder1, here folder1 is the sub directory inside test directory

Comment: Is there any way I can copy only selected sub folders

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Maven will ignore empty directories, and your `include` clause only marks that specific subdirectory, so it will not be copied (because you haven't included any files in that subdirectory). To include files in a subdirectory, use wildcards: `folder1/*` for files directly in that directory or `folder1/**` for files in that directory and its subdirectories (`*` stands for "any file or directory", `**` stands for "any file or directory path").